# multiprocessing.Pool causes memory error in python

Tags: python-2.7, memory, multiprocessing

I have written a multi process(by python 2.7) program,this is my main code:

```
 def pro_func(id):
     #process a slice of huge csv file and send the output list to               
     #another function

 list_index=[]
 for i in range(0,total_shard_cnt,1):
    list_index.append(i)
 print(list_index)
 pool = Pool(processes=total_shard_cnt)
 result = pool.map(pro_func,list_index)
 print(result)
```

and `pro_func` is a function is executed by each process,it passes the outputlist of the function to another function,but when I run the code it causes **Memoryerror** because:

**the outputs of the pro_func are huge lists,and the code keeps all the results in ram until finishing all processes  and does not finish a process when the pro_func is finished,but keeps all process to finish together**

How can I fix this problem?